# STM8 default EEPROM values COSMIC compiler

Tags: pragma, eeprom, stm8

I'm developing a program using COSMIC 'C' compiler Ver 4.5.3 for STM8 CPU (STM8S003K3) and I want fill the MCU EEPROM with default values during mass production using ST-LINK/V2 device.

In the Manual I read that I have to use the #pragma directive ena I developed a simple code:

```
#pragma space extern [] @eeprom @near
static char pippo[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
#pragma space extern [] @near
```

I compiled and linked the code buy  I noticed that the EEPROM section remanins empty. I reported some lines of .map file

```
start 00008080 end 00008145 length   197 segment .const
start 00008145 end 00009722 length  5597 segment .text
start 00004000 end 00004000 length     0 segment .eeprom
start 00000000 end 00000000 length     0 segment .bsct
```

Did you have a similar problem ?
How did you fix it ?
Thank you very much for your help and cooperation
regards

Answer (score 0):

I think by writing `@eeprom @near` you are overwriting the `@eeprom` so leave out the `@near` and you should be good to go.
If you dont have a huge amount of declarations that you want to bee placed in eeprom you can just write the `@eeprom` in front of each declaration like so:

```
@eeprom static char pippo[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
```